# Why is Damavand Peak never a playable map on Conquest xbox360?

Tags: xbox-360, battlefield-3

I don't know if the other platforms or games have this problem, but Damavand Peak is never a map when I play Conquest on the xbox 360.  My Primus playing guide shows it has a Conquest map, so what's the deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I primarily play Conquest, and played Damavand Peak several times over the weekend.
Try using the Server Browser under the Multiplayer menu to find a game that meets your map & game type preferences versus "Quick Match"
Below is a screen capture from Battlelog.Battlefield.com
[image]

Comment: he is on XBox 360.

Comment: @Bora. I'm not sure if you are stating that the OP is on Xbox (Which he is), or that I am. The Battlelog screen clip is from a summary of my game on Xbox. (The logo is just below the "Battle Report:Conquest" title.

Comment: Wow, didn't know they invaded the XBox too.

Comment: BattleReport says Conquest, it has the XBox green logo and the map name is Damavand Peak so so yes you can play that map on the Xbox in Conquest mode.  I have played it myself and have a similar screenshot.  @Micheal Pryor - I guess you have just been 'unlucky'.